# How to configure Angular v15.2 standalone application with MSAL

Tags: angular, msal-angular, angular-standalone-components

Before in ngModule base angular application you use to add MsalRedirectComponent in the bootstrap property of AppModule :

```js
bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
```

Now in V15.2 the AppModule have been replace by the boostrapApplication function in main.ts :

```js
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        importProvidersFrom(
            BrowserModule,
            AppRoutingModule,
           ),       
        provideAnimations(),
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())
    ]
})
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

How to add the MsalRedirectComponent bootstrap ?

I try to add an other call after the first :

```js
bootstrapApplication(MsalRedirectComponent, {
    providers: [
        importProvidersFrom(
            BrowserModule,
            AppRoutingModule,),
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())
    ]
})
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

But this didn't work, the redirect didn't fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For information, i post my working solution :
I decide to not use the extends class, instead i use the handleRedirectObservable build in Msal property.

In main.ts I add the router for auth:

```js
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {

    providers: [
         provideRouter([{ path: 'auth', loadComponent: () => import('@azure/msal-angular').then(mod => mod.MsalRedirectComponent) }]),

        importProvidersFrom(
            BrowserModule,
            AppRoutingModule,
           ),       
        provideAnimations(),
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())
    ]
})
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styles: [],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,RouterOutlet]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(  
    private msalService: MsalService,
  ) {
     }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.msalService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: For me this solution helped except I didn't add the 'auth' in the provedRouter and I didn't subscribe to the handleRedirect in the app component, instead in the service.

 handleRedirect$: Observable<AuthenticationResult> = this.msalService.handleRedirectObservable();

And then in the ngOnInit() {
  this.handleRedirect$.pipe(takeUntil(this._destroying$)).subscribe();
}

Comment: I used auth because i prefered to separate the auth callback from the 'real' routes navigation. For the handleRedirect, msalService is already a service, so I didn't see the use of re-wraped it in a service for only a single observable.

Comment: For me it did not work. :(

Answer (score 5):

MSAL now officially supports Standalone components:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        ...
        provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: MsalInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
            useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
        },
        {
            provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
            useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
        },
        {
            provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
            useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
        },
        MsalService,
        MsalGuard,
        MsalBroadcastService
    ]
})
```

See the docs: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v3-samples/angular-standalone-sample

Answer (score 3):

I'm not working with `MsalRedirectComponent` but it is a normal Component which manage redirects. Try `extends` on your `app.component` like this:

```
export class AppComponent extends MsalRedirectComponent {
  // Normal code....
}
```

The `ngOnInit` will be called in the `MsalRedirectComponent`. I hope it helps.

If you need it you can override it inside your `AppCompnent`

```
//...
override ngOnInit(): void {
  super.ngOnInit();
  // Your stuff
}
//...
```

### Update

I have test it (with other components) and multiple call `bootstrapApplication` will work. You need to set the entry point in your **index.html** like this:

```
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-redirect></app-redirect>
</body>
</html>
```

Then it should work.

**Note** NgModules are not "removed"! Standalone Components are only a new alternative to NgModules. So you can work with it!

Comment: Thx it's working, but it's not the most intuitive way... before : a simple array, after : extends a class and override methods...

Comment: Question : How the angular cli know witch selector to use (app-root or app-redirect), we extends the base class (MsalRedirectComponent) and all two have a différent selector ?

Comment: the app-root is the name of the Components selector (App.Component) and the app-redirect its the name of the MsalRedirectComponent (see in Github). If you change the name in the html as example you will see an error in the browsers console.

Comment: This helped me at first but then I changed it to the accepted answer, bcs this approach creates 2x app-root. You can check when in Angular Develop tools.